# Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view in my notification app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-notifications

i have developed a notification application where on clicking on nitification one activity need to open . but when i click on the notification icon at the top corner of my emulator nothing happens. it should open the NotificationView activity. in the logcat data i found a warning `W/InputMethodManagerService(1214): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b4e4dbd8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b4a95d50`
files are as bellow ...
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.notification1;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   Button b1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Notify("You've received new message","ghfghfghfghf hfghfdgh f fgj f gjdf fghfg");
         }
      });
   }
   private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

      Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

      notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle,notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
      int notificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
      notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification); 


   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

NotificationView.java

```
package com.example.notification1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class NotificationView extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.notification);
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notification1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Notification Example"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="30dp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="hello world "
      android:textColor="#ff87ff09"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

   <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageButton"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Notification"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"
      android:text="Hi, Your Detailed notification view goes here...." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, or the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, to the Intent

Also add a task stach builder

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

hope,this will help you

Comment: on the intent..like intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: in mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); line getting error for mBuilder . what can i do to fix it?

Comment: you can find an example here at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

Try it and let me know :)

Comment: OMG you saved me Thanks alot